# Lucence: filter on multiple fields

Tags: lucene

my lucene index contains records like

id: 12345, code: AN1234, type:Document, author:Brijesh, Sachin
id: 093409, code: XYA1234, type:Paper, author:Brijesh

Now I need to query on "1234", so my base query would be based on keyword "1234"
and then I need to apply filters to get only those records that have
a) author: Brijesh and type: Document, within the base result of 1234

b) author: Sachin or Brijesh,  type:Paper

How do I achieve this using luecene filters ?

Any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [QueryWrapperFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/QueryWrapperFilter.html) to turn any query into a filter. It sounds like your two filters are `+author:brijesh +type:document` and `+(author:brijesh author:sachin) +type:paper` but it's not that clear.

Also I'm not sure if you mean filter in the Lucene sense of the word or if you just want to conjunct some terms. In the latter case just make a standard query.